# Why is my output repeating?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, output, alert

I want to alert "running function cannons" then when I press ok I want it just to say "cannon ship sails off to 14 degrees" but it keeps printing the alert within my output.

**JS**

```
function alertMessage (message) {
alert (message);
}
alertMessage("the Battle has begun");



function alertShip (ship, number) {
alert (ship);
document.write (ship + "the ship sails off to " + number + "degrees");

}
alertShip("running function cannons", 14);
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Functions</title>

    <!-- This links to the js code specific for this page -->
    <script src="functions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>



  <div id="output"> </div>  
 <div id="output2"> </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try it without document.write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't give them the same variable to output .. alert (ship) then document.write (ship+.....).
Try this instead

```
function alertShip (ship, number) {
alert (ship);
document.write ("Cannon ship sails off to " + number + "degrees");
```

Comment: Thank you. that's what it was.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the ship parameter from the document.write and replacing the statement with this:

document.write("cannon ship sails off to " + number + " degrees");

Then, you should be able to get your desired output.

*p.s.: if you're doing this on a text editor and trying to run this on a browser, you can consider changing the  tag to this: .

I hope this helps!